# No puedo renderizar los datos de la API en Angular2

Tags: api, angular, typescript

Tengo mi componente ContactosLista pero no puedo mostrar los nombres del arreglo en la vista, que esta mal en mi código

**ContactosLista.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-gatolista',
  templateUrl: './gatolista.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gatolista.component.css']
})
export class GatolistaComponent implements OnInit {
  private apiUrl = 'http://addressbook-api.herokuapp.com/contacts';
  public contactos;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.contactos = data;
    });
  }

}
```

**contactos.html**

```
<div class="card">
    <div *ngFor="let contacto of data.contacts">
        <h3>{{contacto.first}}</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Prueba `*ngFor="let contacto of contactos"`

Comment: No funciona Maicoly! no se a que se deba el error

Comment: te recomiendo imprimir el salida `data` que tipo de dato arroja `string` o `json`?

Comment: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Comment: También no veo en el caso tengas un error `error => {console.log(error);}`

Comment: en tu caso seria `contactos.contacts`, o a la hora de asignar los contactos deberias de usar `this.contactos = data.contacts` por lo que puedo ver

Comment: Funcionó de la manera que comentas Victor     <div *ngFor="let contacto of contactos.contacts">